# Is there a way to save a Gensim doc2vec model as plain text (.txt)?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

What I have achieved so far are models that can not be read by a person. I need to save the model as plain text to use it with a certain software, which requires that the model be this way.

I tried the following:

```
model = models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(size=300, min_count=0, alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)
model.save('mymodel.txt')
```

But I get:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

I do not know if I should pass a specific parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native gensim `save()` has no plain-text option: it makes use of Python core functionality like object-pickling, or writing large raw floating-point arrays (to secondary files with extra extensions `.npy`). Such files will include raw binary data – and merely specifying a `.txt` filename doesn't have any affect on what is written.

You can save *just* the word-vectors into the one-vector-per-line, plain-text format used by the original Google `word2vec.c` by using the alternate method `save_word2vec_format()`. Also, recent versions of gensim `Doc2Vec` add an optional `doctag_vec` option to this method. If you supply `doctag_vec=True`, the doctag vectors will also be saved to the file – with their tag-names distinguished from word-vectors by an extra prefix. See the method's doc-comment and source-code for more info:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/b000b4fa71386235ffa2b80a62bcccf73fa42c6e/gensim/models/doc2vec.py#L635

However, no variant of `save_word2vec_format()` saves the *entire* model, with internal model-weights and the vocabulary/doctag information (like relative frequencies) that are necessary for continued training. For that, you must use the native `save()`. If you need the full `Doc2Vec` model in a text format, you'll need to write that save code yourself, perhaps using the above method as a partial guide. (Additionally, I'm not aware of a preexisting convention for representing a whole model – so you'd have to find or devise that yourself, to match your needs wherever the full model is later-to-be-loaded.)

Separately regarding your `Doc2Vec` initialization parameters:

- a `min_count=0` is usually a bad idea: rare words make models worse, so the default of `min_count=5` usually improves models, and as your corpus gets larger, even larger `min_count` values discarding more low-frequency words tend to help model quality (as well as speeding training and shrinking the model's RAM/save sizes)
- a `min_alpha` the same as `alpha` is usually a bad idea, and means that `train()` is no longer performing the linear-decay of the `alpha` learning-rate that's the usual and effective manner of performing stochastic-gradient-descent optimization of the model

Comment: This seems to fix all the save problems: https://codekansas.github.io/blog/2016/gensim.html